# Ошибка android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ... (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Есть таблица, в ней колонки:

```
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHECKBOX = "Checkbox";
    public static final String COLUMN_PROKRUTKA = "Prokrutka";
```

При попытке достать значение из последнего столбца пои имени первого вылетает указанная ошибка
Прочитал абсолютно все аналогичные темы на форуме, ничего не помогает. Сразу отпишусь, что все указанные столбцы в таблице есть, сама таблица есть, на приложении ее версия актуальная (приложение почистил, удалил и установил заново), кроме того, другая активность в приложении также использует значение `"Prokrutka"` из таблицы и там все работает.
Вот код, из-за которого вылетает ошибка:

```
@Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int ow, int oh) {
                Intent position = getIntent();
                int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
                sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db = sqlHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    String[] columns=new String[]{"_id","Prokrutka"};
                    Cursor c = db.query("ppvs", columns, "_id =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(positionValue)},null,null,null);
                    if(c.moveToFirst()){
                    prokrutka  = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Prokrutka"));
                }
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, ow, oh);
                if (getContentHeight() > 0) scrollTo(0, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(prokrutka)));
            }
```

Лог ошибки прилагаю
[Лог ошибки текстом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mrr116i1mca3xuc/log.txt?dl=0)
[Лог ошибки картинкой](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lr5dy1lp9ewqzm6/IMG_20191222_164119.jpg?dl=0)

```
class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    private static String DB_NAME = "ppvs.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 6; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "ppvs"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER = "Number";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CHECKBOX = "Checkbox";
    public static final String COLUMN_PROKRUTKA = "Prokrutka";
    private Context myContext;

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath() + DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Вот этот код гарантированно и как и задумано работает с этой же базой и этими же колонками в базе:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try {
            db = sqlHelper.open();
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
            String[] headers = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PROKRUTKA};
            userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

            // если в текстовом поле есть текст, выполняем фильтрацию
            // данная проверка нужна при переходе от одной ориентации экрана к другой
            if(!userFilter.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                userAdapter.getFilter().filter(userFilter.getText().toString());

            // установка слушателя изменения текста
            userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
                // при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    userAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: но в ошибке написано, что отсутствует таблица ppvs, а не столбец prokrutka

Comment: Ну раз есть столбец, то есть и таблица )) Судя по практике таких ошибок - дело чаще всего не в отсутствии таблица, а в чем то другом ((

Comment: @ru38irk, если в ошибке идёт речь про отсутствие таблицы - 99,(9)% что таблицы в БД нет.  Выполните в БД такой запрос `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'` и посмотрите есть ли таблица. Также проверьте код создания оной в БД. Может он у вас не выполнился. Или миграция какая-то не исполнилась. Или у вас сбоит механизм обновления кода приложения на лету. Это можно обойти удалением и новой установкой приложения.

Comment: Проверил. Таблица есть, находится на месте. Вообще пользователь ее не создает - он может только перезаписывать два столбца.. БД создана на компьютере и помещена в приложение. Я в топике написал, что эта же таблица (а точнее даже этот же столбец) используется другой активностью - там все работает. Приложение тестирую на реальном устройстве - устанавливал и с повышением версии базы, и просто удалением приложения и установкой пересобранного с обновленной базой. Не работает именно этот код ((

Comment: Приложите код ошибки текстом, а не картинкой. Не исключен вариант что вы используете не правильные наименования таблиц. Для того чтобы это избежать можете сделать статичные переменные со всеми наименованиями таблиц и колонок - тогда можно будет с уверенностью говорить о том где ошибка. Пока не исключено что присутствует опечатка/не верная кодировка.

Comment: Добавил текстовый фал с логом ошибки. Вроде везде статичные наименования таблицы и ее колонок (только в одном месте они указаны переменными, но там задан аргумент, по моему по другому никак)

Comment: Уверены, что именно на этот код указывает ошибка (в логах значится класс `ru.erstendev.read.Read`)? В обеих активностях используется один и тот же `DatabaseHelper` и одинаковые имена таблицы (почему вообще имена в запросе не константы)? И последнее: в ошибке условие `WHERE .id =?` - откуда взялась точка вместо подчёркивания, в приложенном коде ведь всё правильно?

Comment: @woesss Именно этот rjl jib,jxysq, так как без него все работает. Этот код внутри активности .Read, поэтому она в логах. Имя таблицы подтягивается из DatabaseHelper (это вообще вспомогательная активность для работы с базой, в ней все имена, а также подписанный контракт). Правильно в ошибке WHERE _id =? а не WHERE .id =? Это при копировании в тхт сбой произошел. Не совсем понял насчет констант - вроде везде константы, кроме аргумента, для которого переменную сформулировал тут же.

Comment: Ну и _id фактически формируется прямо там в коде, но это так и задумано - требуется подтянуть значение из базы для конкретного _id, значение которого формируется тут же

Comment: @ru38irk, имеется введу что вместо `db.query("ppvs"...` вместо строки должна быть строковая константа `db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_PPVS...` и тд по коду.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `DatabaseHelper` и пример кода где всё работает с таблицей `ppvs`

Comment: @Andrey Mihalev добавил. Попробовал заменить все на константы, эффект тот же

Comment: Причем после замены всех этих строк на константы содержание ошибки один в один такое же

Comment: В первом случае вы получаете дефолтную базу, созданную хелпером (`getReadableDatabase()`), во втором скопированную вами из ассетов (кастомным методом `open()`). Дело в том, что вы неправильно формируете путь к базе и вместо перезаписи её в стандартном расположении создаёте в другом месте. Посмотрите примеры AssetHelper-а, их не мало в сети.

Comment: Спасибо, буду посмотреть

Comment: А не подскажите, можно ли мою задачу решить не с помощью AssetHelper, а посредством уже имеющегося у меня SQLiteOpenHelper? Или подскажите пример по использованию  AssetHelper? Все что не нахожу, чушь какая то, ну или минимум информации...(

Comment: Можете взять готовый в виде библиотеки: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper. Минимальный пример есть на странице (да - это весь код). Дополнительные заморочки будут зависеть от того как будет использоваться и обновляться база. По дефолту копируется, если не существует; при повышении версии ищет и выполняет скрипты обновлений в ассетах. Если база только для чтения, можно вызовом `setForcedUpgrade` указать, чтобы старая база просто заменялась новой без всяких скриптов.